# Recovering Windows 8 folder C:\Users\my_user

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, data-recovery, user-profiles

I had a problem with a bug on windows 8 where it is stuck in an automatic repair loop. I tried all possible solutions without success. Many ppl are facing the same problem. I tried many checkups and theres no problem with my HDD. Ok... I tried an alternative solution, using ubuntu dvd but it dont recognized my ex-primary partition.

Searching at some forums, I found a command and tried:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
```

Ok, Ubuntu recognized my partition, but the folder C:\Users\my_user was blocked, Linux could not access.

I think Windows 8 uses some crypto to protect these user files. I connected my HD to another computer but now windows 8 cant read this partition, disc utility shows it as invalid.

Any guru has a solution or I lost my files?